# short Unicode \N{} names for Latin-1 characters in Python?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

Are there short Unicode u"\N{...}" names for Latin1 characters in Python ?
\N{A umlaut} etc. would be nice,
\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS} etc. is just too long to type every time.
(Added:) I use an English keyboard, but occasionally need German letters, as in "Löwenbräu Weißbier".
Yes one can cut-paste them singly, L cutpaste ö wenbr cutpaste ä ...
but that breaks the flow; I was hoping for a keyboard-only way.

Comment: What language/regular expression implementation does allow such expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, no, there's no such thing. In string literals, anyway... you could perhaps piggyback on another encoding scheme, such as HTML:

```
>>> import HTMLParser
>>> HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape(u'a &auml; b c')
u'a \xe4 b'
```

But I don't think this'd be worth it.

Hardly anyone even uses the `\N` notation in any case... for the occasional character the `\xnn` notation is acceptable; for more involved usage you're better off just typing `ä` directly and making sure a `# coding=` is defined in the script as per [PEP263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/). (If you don't have a keyboard layout that can type those diacriticals directly, get one. eg. eurokb on Windows, or using the Compose key on Linux.)

Comment: agree, wouldn't be worth it -- was hoping for \N{auml}.
Is there a "compose" on Macs ?

Comment: Not exactly like Compose but apparently you should be able to type `ä` with `Option`+`U` then `A`. http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/accents/codemac.html

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do the right thing please **use UTF-8 in your python source code**. This will keep the code much more readable.

Python is able to real UTF-8 source files, all you have to do is to add an additional line after the first one:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
```

By the way, starting with Python 3.0 UTF-8 is the default encoding so you will not need this line anymore. See [PEP3120](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3120/)

Comment: ok, but (clarification added) I was hoping for \N{aumlaut} or the like, fast to type and clear too

Answer (score 1):

You can put an actual "ä" character in your string. For this you have to declare the encoding of the source code at the top

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

x = u"ä"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about writing your own converter? It wouldn't be hard to write something that would go through a file and replace \N{A umlaut} with \N{LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS} and all the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Unicode notation `\uXXXX` do describe that character:

```
u"\u00E4"
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you can use the charmap.exe utility to look up the keyboard shortcut for common letters you're using such as:

```
ALT-0223 = ß
ALT-0228 = ä
ALT-0246 = ö
```

Then use Unicode and save in UTF-8:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
phrase = u'Löwenbräu Weißbier'
```

or use a converter as someone else mentioned and make up your own shortcuts:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

def german(s):
    s = s.replace(u'SS',u'ß')
    s = s.replace(u'a:',u'ä')
    s = s.replace(u'o:',u'ö')
    return s

phrase = german(u'Lo:wenbra:u WeiSSbier')
print phrase
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to reuse the same characters over and over, I guess you could do something like:

```
od = '\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS}'
ad = '\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS}'
OD = '\N{...}'
#etc
#od stands for o diaeresis, OD stands for O DIAERESIS...
```

and then later:

```
f'L{od}wenbr{ad}u'
```

or something similar.
Not the *simplest* of solutions, but easier to remember (I hope!) than typing in a character code every time you use a special character.